# Wrong application name in PUSH NOTIFICATIONS | ios SWIFT

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

so i was changing the details of an already built ios app and i have changed all the strings etc to change the name of the app, but when the applications gives notification(apple push notifications), it still shows the old app name not the new one. I have also changed the bundle display and bundle package name to the new app name but still not luck.  I also tried cleaning build folder and restarting both my mac and the phone.
In the notification, it displays new name and old name as well, this is very weird.
Please refer to the image below.
[image]

Comment: Old APP Name is coming from server in push notiification data

Comment: This must be from the push-notification service when building the notification content. Ask your backend developer to make updates for app-name. Or if you are using some third party service then go to dashboard and look for the app-name editing options.

Comment: The `New App Name` that you shown is from device. The `Bolt` and its next line, these both lines must be from your server. So, update your server code to have new app name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments from the people above are correct. The **Bolt** data is from your server. The same with your content. So talk to your server/backend guy or do it your self. Also there's a way to somehow handle that.

You can catch the title, the content, and the image (for rich push notification) by adding `Notification Content Extension` and `Notification Service Extension` in your project. That would require a bit of work though. I hope this helps!

Comment: yes, i just figured it, thanks everybody for reaching out

Answer (score 1):

Hey I got the answer from apple developer page. Just follow these options:-

1. Select your Targets
2. Select your Building Settings
3. Check the Packaging.
4. Then check what is the Product Name?

In my case Product Name is the old one.

If still you receive the Old name. So for that case delete the application and install the app now you will receive the New name for the application. No need to right the Notification Content Extension and Notification Service Extension for Push notifications.

Comment: no it was an issue from the back end, but thanks anyways

Comment: Okay but mine case it was my issue

Comment: i will keep it in mind if i run into it again, much appreciated

Comment: This steps works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For changing app name set CFBundleDisplayName value in info.plist file:

CFBundleDisplayName
New app name here

Name specified in this way would be displayed on device under the app icon.
Push notification service depends on app bundle id CFBundleIdentifier.

Comment: i have seen this answer and tried it but didnt work, rather gave an error saying info.plist is invalid